# Why is the total derivative a linear map

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I understand that the total derivative is meant to represent the best linear approximation for a function, but I don't understand why it is a linear map. How do we know that the total derivative is linear at all? If a linear map is defined to be a mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ that satisfies the following properties

$$f(a+b) = f(a) +f(b)$$

and

$$f(Ca)= Cf(a) \text{  for any constant $C$}$$

How do we know that the total derivative satisfies these properties?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The derivative of a linear combination of functions is the linear combination of the derivatives of the functions

Comment: Do you know how to show that the ordinary one-dimensional derivative obeys these two properties?  Can you imagine how you might reduce the larger problem to that of the simpler case?

Comment: you said it: it is a **linear** approximation. The derivative of a function $f:X\to Y$ at a point $p\in X$ exists if and only if there is some linear function $L$ such that $f(p+h)-f(p)=Lh+o(|h|)$ as $|h|\to  0$, then we define the derivative of $f$ at $p$ as $L$. That is: it is linear by definition.

Comment: The definition of a *differentiable* function dictates that such a linear best approximation exists. This is by no means given, but surprisingly often the multivariable functions that occur in 'nature' turn out to be differentiable.

Comment: Write down the expression for the total derivative of a sum as well as the total derivative of a function multiplied by a constant. The proof falls out directly because all of the partial derivatives are linear. Proving that the partial derivatives are linear uses the same reasoning that you use to show that the derivatives of single variable functions are linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total derivative is linear by definition. In fact, $D$ is by definition the total derivative to $f$ in $x_0$ iff $D$ linear so that
$$ \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)-D(x-x_0)}{||x-x_0||} \xrightarrow{x\to x_0} 0 $$

So the total derivative is in fact a bilinear map: If $f,g$ are totally differentiable in $x_0$ with differentials $D_f$, $D_g$. Then for $\lambda,\mu$ we get:
$$ \frac{\lambda f(x)+\mu g(x)-\lambda f(x_0)-\mu g(x_0)-(\lambda D_f +  \mu D_g)(x-x_0)}{||x-x_0||} \xrightarrow{x\to x_0} 0 $$

Thus also $D_{\lambda f+\mu g} = \lambda D_f+\mu D_g$. If that is what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Because, given $p\in\Bbb R^n$ we *define* the total derivative of $f$ at the point $p$ as a *linear map* $L$ from $\Bbb R^n$ into $\Bbb R^m$ such that$$\lim_{x\to p}\frac{f(x)-f(p)-L(x-p)}{\|x-p\|}=0$$(and we prove that if such a linear map exists, then it is unique).